# Installing C# Dev Kit extension in VSCode running within Linux docker container

Tags: c#, linux, docker, visual-studio-code, devkit

I'd like to setup [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit) on VS Code instance available via browser and running within a Linux docker container (I guess it should be a Visual Studio Code Dev Container). The dotnet itself is installed. The issue is that searching for the 'C# Dev Kit' extension is unsuccessful. Is there any other straightforward way to install 'C# Dev Kit' on Linix docker-container? CLI option would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: any specific error message?

Comment: @starball No any specific error messages. The VS Code instance I'm using from within docker container doesn't have C# support, So I thought that `C# Dev Kit` would solve the issue. But `C# Dev Kit` extension isn't available in the list of the extensions to setup when I'm searching it using `C# Dev Kit` search key (see screenshot0.

Comment: It looks like `C# Dev Kit` isn't available for this my environment - docker container. When I'm searching for `C# Dev Kit` extension on VS Code running on MS Win then it's available - first in the list. I should have checked that first of all. 
I'm going to hide/delete this question as it probably doesn't have positive solution.

Comment: you can also write an answer post (see [answer]). Just because there's no "positive solution" doesn't mean it's not useful to others. Granted- I don't know much about C# so I can't tell.